# Help to show a map is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Let $X= \{(z,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 \vert y = z^3\}$, I need to show that map $p$ of projection onto the first coordinate is a homeomorphism. I'm having trouble working with $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: Show that projection is a continuous bijection from $X$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Cbjork That's not sufficient in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Projections are continuous, and so is their restriction to $X$.

Now note that $z \to (z,z^3)$ is its continuous inverse (it's continuous because te compositions with both projections on $\Bbb C^2$ are $Z \to z$ and $z \to z^3$ and are continuous, or use another method if you're more familiar with that). So $\pi_1\restriction X$ is indeed a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_1$ be the projection onto the first coordinate, consider $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$ defined by $f(x)=(x,x^3)$ $f$ is the inverse of $p_1$.